# jQuery append element during $.each()

Tags: append, jquery

I'm trying to repeatedly append an element defined outside the closure in a jQuery `$.each()` loop see - http://jsfiddle.net/benedict_w/8Pczs/

Could someone please explain why the element is only appended in the last iteration of the loop?

e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
</ul>
```

using the following jquery:

```
var remove = $('<a href="#">remove</a>');
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).append(remove);       
});​
```

producers:

```
<ul>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah <a href="#">remove</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Here is a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/benedict_w/MJcyD/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're appending the *same* element each time.
Each append will move it to the next `<li>`.

You need to `clone()` the element (or just re-create it) for each iteration.

Comment: Thanks this is the closest to an explanation.

Comment: While this is the best explanation (which is what I asked for) please see @ThiefMaster for the solution that I have implemented  - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12411151/664125

Comment: @benedict_w: That's what I meant by "re-create it".

Answer (score 2):

```
$('<a href="#">remove</a>').appendTo('li');
```

This will append a new element to each `li` while avoiding unnecessary loop and jQuery object creations.

> If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target after the first, and that new set (the original element plus clones) is returned.

http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Comment: Thanks - that's useful, would I be able to chain a click handler to the link here too? e.g. `$('<a href="#">remove</a>').click(function() {...}).appendTo('li');`

Comment: Yes, it uses `.clone(true)` which also clones data and events.

Comment: Yes this works with the click handler too - as demonstrated: http://jsfiddle.net/benedict_w/MJcyD/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to clone the element to be inserted. According to the definition of [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('li').append('<a href="#">remove</a>'); 
//will append an <a> to every <li> in the "set of matched elements"
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/LwfPg/1/)

**UPDATE**:
If you do need the `each()` iterator to do other things, why not define your element inside of the closure?

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var remove = $('<a href="#">remove</a>');
    $(this).append(remove);       
    //do other things
});​
```

**UPDATE 2**: Just keeping answer upto date from what I learned from OP's comments

Because in your question, you have reference to one unique element(defined outside the closure). Which, gets appended to the DOM on the first iteration. The next time you're trying to append that same element at another node in the DOM. jQuery recognizes that and so, detaches it from its place, creates another document fragment, then attaches it to its new target in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks - the example I've given is deliberately simplified as I wanted to clarify the behaviour. In this case I would also need to bind a click handler to the link.

Comment: @benedict_w: You should have stated your problem as-is. :(  Anyways, in your question just **define the `remove` inside of the closure** and you're done. Everything else seems like beating around the bush to me now.

Comment: Thanks for your input my question was not how to fix it but why it happens - 'Could someone please explain why the element is only appended in the last iteration of the loop?'

Comment: @benedict_w: Because in your question, you have reference to one unique element. So you're trying to append that same element over and over again. jQuery recognizes that and removes that element before appending it again elsewhere in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Define variable "remove" as plain text, that is

```
var remove = '<a href="#">remove</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var remo[enter link description here][1]ve = $(
```

is messing up your code. It is appending the element because of which it is happening.. Just pass it as a string instead of a selector or clone the object.. that should get the work  done for you,,

```
var remove = '<a href="#">remove</a>' ;
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).append(remove);       
});​
```

Also you can use appendTo to avoid the iteration

```
$('<a href="#">remove</a>').appendTo('li');
```

check the [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/benedict_w/8Pczs/)