# jQuery: append() for each element

Tags: jquery

I have a table and a list:

```
<table>
  <tr>
       <td>Jack</td>
       <td class="date"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
       <td>David</td>
       <td class="date"></td>
  </tr>

  ...
</table>

<hr />

<span class="inline-date">2012</span>
<span class="inline-date">2013</span>
```

I want to append each `span.inline-date` to each `td.date` like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
       <td>Jack</td>
       <td class="date"><span class="inline-date">2012</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
       <td>David</td>
       <td class="date"><span class="inline-date">2013</span></td>
  </tr>

  ...
</table>
```

I tired:

```
  
  $("span.inline-date").appendTo('table td.date');
```

But I get double `span` in each `td`.

I miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) like this;

```
var cells = $('table td.date');

$('span.inline-date').each(function (i) {
    cells.eq(i).append($(this));
});
```

Comment: You might also want to use `clone()` to keep the original element in place. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12411119/156973)